# MySQL enum equivalent in Objective-C other than enum?

Tags: objective-c

I'm pulling data from an online database. One of the columns has the data type ENUM('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', Friday', 'Saturday') in the MySQL database.

I was wondering whether it is fine to just save it as NSString in the class object or there's a more efficient way to do so, such as creating a type definition of an object that can only be one of the ENUM parameters that speeds up processing or saves space, such as when they are used in MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a corresponding C `enum` and which will store it as an integer type in memory. This will be faster/smaller than storing it in an `NSString`, but unless you're doing something quite unusual (i.e. processing gazillions of records) I would not expect the difference to be noticeable. If you do choose make a C `enum` for this purpose, you will probably end up writing routines to convert it back and forth to/from `NSString`s, which is a minor, yet annoying chore.

The idiomatic thing to use for `enums` like this in Objective-C these days is the `NS_ENUM` macro. See [this page](http://nshipster.com/ns_enum-ns_options/) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Appreciate the prompt reply. I've looked up NS_ENUM and normal enum's.

Comment: My SQL ENUM data might return a word with spaces. I could do `temperature = json.temp;` in which **json.temp** would be "very hot". However, I can't assign a word with spaces for the ENUM typedef. `typedef enum {
    hot,
    veryHot,
    normal,
    cool,
    freezing
} tempType;` 

This means that I would have to use an if-statement to decide the value of the ENUM. Would the if-statement and a formatToString method really be better than simply assigning the value to a string?

Would it be better to use that approach or just a simple String?

Comment: I would just use a string, myself.